# Mongoose Query: inserting html separators according to object parameter

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I've recently started to dive into JavaScript and NodeJS to build a project for my thesis.

I have a collection (plants) with a property for its objects (gardener: String)

It's being queried on the route:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    Plant.find({}).sort('gardener').exec(function(err, plants){
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        else {
            res.render("index", {plants: plants}); 
        }
    });
});
```

---

How can I show all plants but PLACE A SEPARATOR for each gardener? (a gardener will be a user, therefore, can be limited)

Something like

```
<h4>Gardener <%=plant.gardener%></h4>
[here goes a list of the plants of this gardener]
```

For instance (rendering of /):

```
<h4>Gardener Mary</h4>
... (list of Mary's plants)

<h4>Gardener Joseph</h4>
... (list of Joseph's plants)

<h4>Gardener George</h4>
... (list of George's plants)

[...]
```

P.S.: I know the best is to define gardener as a reference for a user, but that will be the next step :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your else statement you could reorganize your plants array:

```
var newPlants = [];
var aux = [];
var previousGardener = "";

plants.forEach(function(plant) {
    if(previousGardener === plant.gardener) {
        aux.push(plant);
        return ;
    }
    if(previousGardener !== "") {
       newPlants.push({ gardener: previousGardener, plants: aux });
       aux = [];
    }
    aux.push(plant);
    previousGardener = plant.gardener;
});

if(aux.length > 0)    newPlants.push({ gardener: previousGardener, plants: aux });
res.render("index", { plants: newPlants });
```

And your html would be something like:

```
<% for(var i = 0 ; i < plants.length ; i++) { %>
    <h4><%= plants[i].gardener %></h4>
    <ul>
    <% for(var j = 0 ; j < plants[i].plants.length ; j++) { %>
        <li><%= plants[i].plants[j].description %></li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>
 <% } %>
```

I wrote this on the fly so apologies if something is wrong.

And happy new year as well :)

Comment: Wait. It's not showing all objects... It's somehow hiding some objects.

Comment: Can you do console.log(newPlants) before the res.render and post it here?

Comment: `newPlants: 
[ { gardener: 'mary',
    plants: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { gardener: 'john', plants: [ [Object] ] } ]
-------------------------`

Seems like it's eating a plant of each gardener before passing

Comment: Worked for the first gardener, printed all her plants, but still ate one plant of the second gardener xD

Comment: console.log(aux); seems to be printing the second from the last of the last gardener...

Comment: Works like a charm :D